# Only SOAP12 is configured, but got error "Incoming SOAP message protocol is version 1.1"

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere, jax-ws

I've configured WebService in WebSphere (7) using JAX-WS. In the last week everything was tested, but today, after cleanup and refresh, I get an error:

> Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Incoming SOAP message
>   protocol is version 1.1, but endpoint is configured for SOAP 1.2. 
>   This is not supported.    at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1310)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1036)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:529)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:470)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:377)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:185)

What is the most suprising, SOAP 1.1 was never configured there. From begin only SOAP 1.2 was used. Here is the digest from my WSDL:

```xml
<wsdl:definitions name="ucmdbservice"
    targetNamespace="http://service.my/v3" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://service.my/v3"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <wsdl:binding name="binding_soap12_v3" type="tns:v3">

        <soap12:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="getResult">
            <soap12:operation
                soapAction="http://service.my/v3/getResult" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="service_v3">
        <wsdl:port name="port_soap12_v3" binding="tns:binding_soap12_v3">
            <soap12:address location="http://host.my/v3"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

This are the header annotations of Servlet class:

```
@javax.jws.WebService(wsdlLocation = "wsdl/myservice_v3.wsdl", 
       endpointInterface = "my.service.V3", 
       targetNamespace = "http://service.my/v3", 
       serviceName = "myservice_v3", 
       portName = "port_soap12_v3")
@javax.xml.ws.BindingType(value = javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
```

and the annotations of client, generated from the same WSDL:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "myservice_v3", 
    targetNamespace = "http://service.my/v3", 
    wsdlLocation = "../../wsdl/myservice_v3.wsdl")
```

Everything was already worked. It is tested in IBM RAD 8.0, so I suppose some RAD-issue, rather then WebSphere-issue or JAX-WS-issue, but it could be so, I don't see something obvious missing in definition.

Notice: service names and namespaces are changed for the confidentiality reason, so don't look for namespace mismatches :)

Comment: If your SOAP client is issuing a SOAP 1.1. request, then this is the message you should expect in your server.  It seems the focus of your investigation should be the SOAP client.  Why is it sending SOAP 1.1 request payloads instead of respecting the SOAP 1.2 bindings mandated in your WSDL?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with client, and specifically, with client stub constructor generated by JAX-WS.

I've solved the problem by calling 3-argument constructor:

```
MyServiceV3 service = new MyServiceV3(
  MyService.class.getResource("/wsdl/myservice_v3.wsdl",
  new QName("http://service.my/v3"), "myservice_v3");
```

instead of no-argument constructor, which was based on the output of that strage generated code:

```
  baseUrl = MyServiceV3 .class.getResource(".");
  url = new URL(baseUrl, "../../wsdl/myservice_v3.wsdl");
```